# How to place a table at the top of page in Appendix (IEEE bare conf template)

Tags: tables, tabularx, ieeeconf

I am using the IEEE [bare_conf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-bare-demo-template-for-conferences/ypypvwjmvtdf) template. I have couple of tables in my document. One is a two column table which is going to a separate page. But, the table is showing at the middle of the page. Note that this is my last table in the document. I tried a different combination but could not place in other place because of the combination of other tables.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=0.675\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.325\hsize}X}
\begin{table*}[t!]
\centering
\caption{Sample Table}
\label{tags-keywords-table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {|b | s |}
 \hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Column1}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Column2}}\\
 \hline \hline
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


 
 &  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

I tried with `ht!` or `htp` but could not place the table at the top of the page where there is no other content. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please extend your code sniped to complete small document (MWE).

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding something like this to your document. It may affect your other tables though, so check and see of they are still okay.

```
 % force tables to top of page, 25pt space
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{25pt}
\makeatother
```